# $C⊆A$ and $D⊆B$ and A and B are disjoint, then C and D are disjoint.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Let A,B,C and D be sets. How to prove:

> $C\subseteq A$ and $D\subseteq B$ and $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, then $C$ and $D$ are disjoint.

Could anyone please explain to me how to approach this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the definition of disjoint sets. If A and B are disjoint, then: for any $x \in A \implies x\notin B$, for any $y \in B \implies y\notin A$, i.e., $A$ and $B$ are disjoint if and only if $A\cap B = \varnothing$.

Now, we can prove your statement using a proof by contradiction:

***Suppose*** $C$ and $D$ are ***NOT*** disjoint, i.e. suppose $C\cap D\neq \varnothing$. Then there exists an $x \in C\cap D.\;$ Then $x \in C$ and $x \in D$. In particular, that element $x$ is in $A$ since it's in $C\subseteq A$, and it's in $B$, since it's in $D\subseteq B$. So  $x\in A\cap B$, which means $A\cap B \neq \varnothing.\;$ But wait: by hypothesis, $\;A\cap B =\varnothing\;$ ***Contradiction***...

Therefore our supposition must be false, as it leads to a contradiction. Hence, it must be the case that $C$ and $D$ are disjoint.

Comment: Woah!, you're quick. Thanks, for the explanation, now I think I have an idea on how to do it. :)

Comment: Excellent! You're welcome :-)

Comment: Would you mind to walk me through another similar question but a little more challenging? :P

Comment: Very nice, $\text{Amy}_{y\to\infty}$

Answer (score 2):

Since $C \subset A$ and $D \subset B$, you have $(C \cap D) \subset (A \cap B)$, and since $A \cap B = \emptyset$, we have $C \cap D = \emptyset$.

Answer (score 0):

Pick elements $c \in C$ and $d\in D$.  Since $c\in C$, $c \in A$, so that $c\not\in B$.  Every element of $D$ is an element of $B$, so $c\not\in D$.  By symmetry, $d\not\in C$.  Therefore, $C$ and $D$ have no elements in common.  That is, $C\cap D$ is empty.